# How I can use Keyboard interaction in this code

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

i want to use keyboard key to move the object on the path but after using    keyboard function the object is not moving.Please help me with this.after applying keyboard function the object is not moving from its place.

> i want to add 3 different function for wave/path so keyboard interaction is necessary for me, so that i may able to use different keys for different scenes.

```cpp
void object()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex2f(-0.3, 0.1);
    glVertex2f(0.3, 0.1);        
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
}

void drawsine()
{   glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);//Primitive
    glColor3f(255, 0, 0);//Set drawing color 
    int i = 0;
    float x = 0, y = 0;
    for (x = -5; x < 6; x = x + 0.1)
    {   y = (sin(3.142*x)) / 3.142*x;
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        sinex[i] = x;
        siney[i] = y;
        i++;}
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void doFrame(int v) {
    //x = sinex[i];
    //y = siney[i];
    if (x < 5.9)
    {
        x += 0.1;
        y = (sin(3.142*x)) / 3.142*x;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
    //glutTimerFunc(x,doFrame,0);
}

void scene1()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();
    drawsine();
    glPopMatrix();


    //glScaled(0.3, 0.3, 1);
    object();


    //glutTimerFunc(30,doFrame,0);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void exit(void)
{
    exit(-1);
}

void myKeyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case 'h':
    {
        scene1();   }
    break;

    case 'e':
    {
        exit(); }
    break;
    }
}

void display() {

    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


}

void init() {
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-5, 7, -5, 5, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(700, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Roller Coaster Simulation");

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutTimerFunc(200, doFrame, 0);
    glutKeyboardFunc(myKeyboard);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code? It would help us understand where the problem is.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i have now provided the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to draw the scene in the display callback [`glutDisplayFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html).

Add a scene state (`current_scene`) and switch the state when a key is pressed:

e.g.

```cpp
int current_scene = 1;

void myKeyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch (key) {
       case 'h': current_scene = 1; break; 
       case 'i': current_scene = 2; break; 
       // [...]
   }
}
```

Draw a scene dependent on the state in the display callback:

```cpp
void display() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    switch(current_scene) {
        case 1: scene1(); break;
        case 2: scene2(); break;
        // [...]
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

I recommend to do the buffer swap ([`glutSwapBuffers`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node21.html)) in `disaply` only. Remove it form the other functions.
Use [`glutPostRedisplay`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node20.html) to mark the current window as needing to be redisplayed continuously.

Comment: @HooriaKhalid [Lighthouse3d.com](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/) has a GLUT Tutorial that might be worth to have a look on.